# Android kotlin Billing - ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED condition not executed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-billing

I have the latest billing version 6.0.1

This is the function to get the item prices:

```
private fun getPriceSingle(productId: String, priceText: TextView){

    val queryProductDetailsParams =
        QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductList(
                ImmutableList.of(
                    QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                        .setProductId(productId)
                        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                        .build()))
            .build()

    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsParams) { billingResult, productDetailsList ->

        when (billingResult.responseCode) {

            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {

                when (productId) {
                    "no_ads_one_week_de" -> {
                        detailsWeek = productDetailsList[0]
                    }
                    "no_ads_one_month_de" -> {
                        detailsMonth = productDetailsList[0]
                    }
                    "no_ads_one_year_de" -> {
                        detailsYear = productDetailsList[0]
                    }
                }

                val price = productDetailsList[0].subscriptionOfferDetails?.get(0)?.pricingPhases!!.pricingPhaseList[0]?.formattedPrice.toString()

                priceText.text = price

                if(detailsWeek != null && detailsMonth != null && detailsYear != null){
                    allPricesSet = true
                    binding.loadingPanelVip.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> {
                Toasty.success(this@GetPremium, "Billing is not supported on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG, true).show()
                finish()
            }
            BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED -> {
                Log.d("pikaboo", "owned")
                premiumActivate()
            }
            else -> {
                getPriceSingle(productId, priceText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I've purchased and acknowledget one of them the items, I can see it in the subscriptions in the google play account.

Now when I call the function again to request the same item price, the `BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED` condition doesn't get executed

Why is that and how to fix?